# Play Framework redirect not working in Safari

Tags: redirect, solr, safari, xmlhttprequest, playframework-2.0

I'm attempting to query Solr from Angular and routing the request through a Play Controller for security and using Play redirect to forward the request to Solr.
This seems to be working on Chrome but not on Safari/Firefox.

Angular ajax request

```
var solrUrl = '/solr';
        storesFactory.getAdvancedMessages = function (searchCriteria, searchType) {

            var filterQuery = solrQueryComposer(searchCriteria);
            $log.warn(filterQuery);
             return $http({
                method: 'GET', 
                url: solrUrl,
                params: {   'q': '*',
                            'fq': filterQuery,
                            'rows': 30,
                            'wt': 'json'}
                }).
                then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $log.debug(data.data.response.docs);
                    return data.data.response.docs;
                },
                function(error){
                    $log.error(error.message);
                });
```

Play Controller

```
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Security;

@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public class SolrController extends Controller {

    private static String solrUrl = "http://whatever.com:5185/solr/select/";
    private static String queryPart = "";
    public static Result forward(){

        queryPart = request().uri().substring(5);
        System.out.println(queryPart);
        return seeOther(solrUrl+queryPart);

    }

}
```

Play Route

```
GET   /solr     controllers.SolrController.forward()
```

Comment: So, what happens instead of what you expect on safari? You get the redirect back in $http().then() or nothing happens at all?

Comment: I'm able to see the requests from Safari and firefox hitting the play controller. The redirect happens and the callback then() is executed but the response is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to clarify what you're doing.

Play is not forwarding anything here, it's sending a redirect to the client, asking to fetch another URL. The client will send a request, receive a redirect, and send another request.

Which means:

- this controller is not "forwarding" anything. It's just tells the client to go somewhere else. ("seeOther", the name speaks for itself).
- It's **not secure at all**. Anyone knowing solr's URL could just query it directly.
- since the query is performed by the client, it may be stopped by the cross-domain security policy.

Moreover, There's a HUGE race condition waiting to happen in your code. `solrUrl` and `queryPart` are static, therefore shared by all threads, therefore **shared by all clients**!!

There's absolutely no reason for `queryPart` to be static, and actually, there's absolutely no reason for it to be in this scope. This variable should be defined in the method body.

I'd also like to point out that `request().uri().substring(5)` is very brittle and is going to break if you change the URL in the route file.

In `return seeOther(solrUrl+queryPart)`, `queryPart` arguments keys and values should also be URLencoded.

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for your inputs on the code, especially the thread awareness. Regarding the security, my solr is expected(in future) to be behind an http filter which will scan for cookies.

Comment: On the problem itself, ideally the second request should not be allowed by the browser as its a cross domain request. But i'm not seeing any such browsers warnings as i'd see if i called the solr url directly from angular.

Comment: The point is you _are_ calling solr directly from the browser.